# change date based on midnight time

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time-series

i have dataframe which contains 3 column for date and time: **date** ,**depart time** and **arrive time**. i want to make two columns of datetime (**depart time and arrive time**) using pandas so I use **to_datetime** function.

since the date column based only on the depart time, there are some cases where the depart time is around 23:00 and the arrive time is after 24:00 but the date stays the same. for instance:

**depart datetime: 01/12/2017 23:58:00 arrive time 01/12/2017 00:30:00**

how can i write a function that will update the day to the day after if the arrive time is after midnight? (in the example  it should be arrive time 02/12/2017)

thanks

Comment: How does it work?

Comment: im not sure I fully understand how does the mask function work but i tried it and it worked perfectly! thank you!

Comment: It working very simple - add 1 day `pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d')` only for rows where boolean mask `m` is `True`. So only for first rows is added day, for second not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can check difference is bellow `0 Timedelta` and by mask add one day:

```
print (df)
           depart time          arrive time
0  01/12/2017 23:58:00  01/12/2017 00:30:00
1  01/12/2017 00:30:00  01/12/2017 23:58:00


df['depart time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['depart time'], dayfirst=True)
df['arrive time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['arrive time'], dayfirst=True)

m = (df['arrive time'] - df['depart time']) < pd.Timedelta(0)
```

Another condition should be:

```
m = (df['depart time'] - df['arrive time']).dt.days != -1

print (m)
0     True
1    False
dtype: bool

df['arrive time'] = df['arrive time'].mask(m, df['arrive time'] + pd.Timedelta(1, unit='d'))
print (df)
          depart time         arrive time
0 2017-12-01 23:58:00 2017-12-02 00:30:00
1 2017-12-01 00:30:00 2017-12-01 23:58:00
```